# Animating Xamarin.Forms ViewCell causes scaling issues and slow performance on iOS

Tags: ios, forms, listview, animation, xamarin

I am currently trying to animate a ViewCell inside a ListView so it expands and collapses once it gets Tapped. The logic behind this works fine, but there seem to be issues with the iOS ListView that I am unable to figure out. The implementation is currently done in the shared code and not platform specific.

The ViewCell itself contains two subviews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          x:Class="com.example.CollapsableCell"
          Appearing="OnAppearing">
    <Frame x:Name="CollapsableFrame" CornerRadius="5" HasShadow="true" Margin="5" BorderColor="Gray" OutlineColor="Gray">
        <Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="CollapsableContent" />
        </Grid>
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>                
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped" />
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    </Frame>
</ViewCell>
```

The method for switching between the collapsed and expanded views looks like this:

```
    protected void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnTapped");
        if (_isExpanded) // collapse the ViewCell
        {
            CollapsableFrame.LayoutTo(_collapsedBounds, 500, Easing.CubicIn);
            ForceUpdateSize();
            CollapsableFrame.BackgroundColor = _collapsedView.BackgroundColor;
            _collapsedView.RotationY = -270.0;
            _expandedView.RotateYTo(-90.0, 250, Easing.SinIn);
            _expandedView.IsVisible = false;
            _collapsedView.IsVisible = true;
            _collapsedView.RotateYTo(-360.0, 250, Easing.SinOut);
            _collapsedView.RotationY = 0.0;
            _isExpanded = false;
        }
        else // Expand the ViewCell
        {
            CollapsableFrame.LayoutTo(_expandedBounds, 500, Easing.CubicOut);
            ForceUpdateSize();
            CollapsableFrame.BackgroundColor = _expandedView.BackgroundColor;
            _expandedView.RotationY = -270.0;
            _collapsedView.RotateYTo(-90.0, 250, Easing.SinIn);
            _collapsedView.IsVisible = false;
            _expandedView.IsVisible = true;
            _expandedView.RotateYTo(-360.0, 250, Easing.SinOut);
            _expandedView.RotationY = 0.0;
            _isExpanded = true;
        }
    }
```

The _collapsedView and _expandedView are private members that are set via properties and are child objects to CollapsableContent,

On Android this works perfect, on iOS the scaling of the CollapsableFrame never works properly (the content extends over the Frames bounds) and in addition after executing the animation a few times the animation gets stuck and freezes the whole application. I already tried to strip the animation down to only the scaling of the CollapsableFrame, but the issue stays the same.

Here are the information of my development environment:

```
Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac
Version 7.6 (build 2190)
Installation UUID: 42ba26db-6c15-44b2-a48a-811339d08d89
Runtime:
    Mono 5.12.0.301 (2018-02/4fe3280bba1) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Xamarin.Mac 4.4.1.178 (master / eeaeb7e6)

    Package version: 512000301

NuGet
Version: 4.3.1.4445

.NET Core
Laufzeit: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Laufzeitversionen:
    2.1.2
    2.1.1
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/Sdks
SDK-Versionen:
    2.1.302
    2.1.301
MSBuild-SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.6.3
Speicherort: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 9.4.1 (14161)
Build 9F2000

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 4.6.0.13 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 373c313a
Branch: 
Build date: 2018-07-24 23:47:12-0400

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 11.14.0.13 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 373c313a
Branch: HEAD
Build date: 2018-07-24 23:47:12-0400

Xamarin.Android
Version: 9.0.0.18 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/ban/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Unterstützte Android-Versionen:
        8.1 (API-Ebene 27)

Version von SDK Tools: 26.1.1
Version der SDK-Plattformtools: 28.0.0
Version der SDK-Buildtools: 27.0.3

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL-Code ist hier verfügbar:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Xamarin Inspector
Version: 1.4.3
Hash: db27525
Branch: 1.4-release
Build date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 21:20:18 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

Build Information
Release ID: 706002190
Git revision: 329690594b336b0b810b0399136d55eb54d292ec
Build date: 2018-08-20 12:03:11+00
Build branch: release-7.6
Xamarin extensions: 23b59d33e3e5e6b7efa0f6d2d699867ab5082527

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.13.6
Darwin 17.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0
    Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018
    root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

I presume that I have to use a custom renderer on iOS to fix this, but at the moment I have no idea where to start. I Hope someone in the community can give me a hint.

Comment: I cannot help you with your specific problem, but how can it compile while having 2 childrens inside a `Frame`? `Frame` can only hold one element.

Comment: The children are added to the grid that is inside of the frame.

Comment: Strange, your xaml shows that you declare two children inside a frame (a frame and a grid)

Comment: This is incorrect, the second element inside the frame is setting the Gesture Recognizer of the Frame itself. It is not a new frame. See this sample for an Image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap#using-xaml

Comment: Ohhhh you are right, how could I miss that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now an official issue pending investigation by the Xamarin.Forms team:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4012